# R ggplot geom_line() - colour by factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a ggplot time series chart with one line where the colour of the line depends on a binary factor variable. Somehow my code generates two lines when I colour by factor:

```
date = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-20"), by = 1)
data = rnorm(20)
factor = as.factor(sample(0:1,20,replace=T))
df = data.frame(date = date, data = data, factor = factor)

p=ggplot(df, aes(date))
p=p + geom_line(aes(y = data, colour = factor))
print(p)
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Set group to 1, i.e. `aes(y = data, colour = factor, group = 1)`. ggplot is trying to be helpful here, and set your grouping automatically (this is what you would usually want), but since you want only a single group you need to set it back to 1.

Comment: This was easy :-) Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm 90% sure it's a duplicate, but I don't have time to find the correct target right now.

Comment: I was also sure to find it somewhere, but so far I did not. If it's a duplicate I am happy to close the question...